# How to pop to root controller in app where root viewcontroller is of type UIViewController?

Tags: swift, appdelegate

I have implemented `SWRevealViewController` class for revealing a rear (left and/or right) view controller behind a front controller. SWRevealViewController of type UIViewController is the entry point in the app.

**What do I want?**
In `class AppDelegate` when `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called, I want to pop all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.

**What I tried?**

```
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I know that if `SWRevealViewController` were embedded in a UINavigationController, I could simply do `(appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` , but it is not embedded in nav controller and if I embed it, then I will not get the same behaviour, so how can I sort this out?

[image]

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682278/poptorootviewcontroller-from-appdelegate-in-swift 
and simply call popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Comment: @aBilal17 as I said, rootViewController is not of type UIViewNavigationController, thus your suggestion is applicable to my use case.

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: @aBilal17  I can't share the project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is an "unwindSegue".

They are are documented in a technical note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

With that you should be able to identify your root view controller as the target of the unwind segue and, of needed, follow the unwind through various steps as it occurs.

You can also look at the documentation for the various methods of UIViewController that contain the term "unwind"

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: I don't intend to use unwind segue. If there are 20 controllers on the stack and the app goes in background mode, then I want to pop to root controller. I would have to build 20 unwind segues, so it's not an option. The desired result is as follows: No matter what is the active view controller on the stack, if the app goes in background mode, then it should pop to root controller, this is the reason I was trying to do make the call from AppDelegate.

Comment: From the tech note "You use unwind segues to "go back" one or more steps in your navigation hierarchy."   An unwind segue is not limited to unwinding just a single stage of navigation.  You should be able to use a single unwind segue to remove 20 levels of your navigation.

Comment: You misunderstood me. You have an array of [ 1...100] `UIViewController`'s. The topMost UIViewController could be any of them. When `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called, we need to pop to rootController. Using unwindSegue, we would need to create an unwind segue for each UIViewController, meaning 100 unwindSegues.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
 let navVC = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window)?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    for VC: UIViewController in (navVC?.viewControllers)! {
        if (VC is MYViewController) {
            navVC?.popToViewController(VC, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```